# Внедрение Блокчейна в Android

Tags: java, android, blockchain

Необходимо внедрить Blockchain разработку в Android приложение. Ни разу с этим не работал. Хотелось бы узнать с чего начинать? Какие варианты реализации есть? Чего почитать по этому поводу, мб есть какие библиотеки?
Благодарю за ответы

Answer (score 2):

Блокчейн, если отвлечься от истерического хайпа поднятого всякими майнерами, это всего лишь способ распределенного сетевого хранения истории транзакций причем обладающего свойством `immutable` то есть неизменяемости.

Неизменность гарантируется - криптографическими хэш функциями. По сути блокчейн - это способ вычисления хэша по распределенной сети. Отсюда следует 2 важных вывода:

1. Должна существовать распределенная сеть клиентов блокчейн работающих по единому протоколу
2. Должен быть единый способ вычисления хэша

Есть 3 основные реализации блокчейна:

1. Bitcoin - API [BitcoinJ](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj), используются клиенты Bitcoin хэш функция SHA-256
2. Etherium - API [Web3J](https://github.com/web3j/web3j), используются клиенты Etherium, хэш функция Ethash (придумка Бутерина на базе SHA-3)
3. HyperLedger Fabric - API [Fabric SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java) - сеть созданная Linux Foundation, используется хэш функция SHA-256